# adding time delay for woocommerce jquery script

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

could u please help me out? This is a script for woocommerce product thumbnails, so if users mouse overs thumbnails it will display it in the main product image box.

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseover','.thumbnails .zoom', function(){
    var photo_fullsize =  jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('-100x100','');
    jQuery('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src', photo_fullsize);
    return false;
});
```

I want to add a little bit of transition to this jquery script. This is to prevent ultra fast switching between woocommerce thumbnails. If i have a lot of thumbnails, and i hold the mouse in one position on thumbnail and product images are different in size, the script will just blink to one image to another - kind of a bug. I think that adding a delay here might get user some time to move my mouse away from next thumbnail image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTimeout:

```
var delay = 3000; //delay in ms
jQuery(document).on('mouseover','.thumbnails .zoom', function(){
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      var photo_fullsize =  jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('-100x100','');
      jQuery('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src', photo_fullsize);
      return false;
    }
  , delay);
});
```